# How can I add data to the index column of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to output the following dataframe

```
Ratio  A  B  C
ROA
ROE
ROI
```

Below is the code that I am trying to run

```
import pandas as pd

col_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']

data = pd.DataFrame([['ROA', 'ROE', 'ROI']], columns=col_list)
data.index.names = ['Ratios']

ratio_rows = ['ROA', 'ROE', 'ROI', 'PE Ratio']

data.set_axis(ratio_rows)
```

When I try to run the last line of code I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  Cell In[7], line 1
data.set_axis(ratio_rows)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py:5034 in set_axis
    return super().set_axis(labels, axis=axis, copy=copy)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:708 in set_axis
    return self._set_axis_nocheck(labels, axis, inplace=False, copy=copy)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:720 in _set_axis_nocheck
    setattr(obj, obj._get_axis_name(axis), labels)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:6002 in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

  File pandas\_libs\properties.pyx:69 in pandas._libs.properties.AxisProperty.__set__

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py:730 in _set_axis
    self._mgr.set_axis(axis, labels)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py:225 in set_axis
    self._validate_set_axis(axis, new_labels)

  File D:\Users\Mahmoud\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\base.py:70 in _validate_set_axis
    raise ValueError(

ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 0 elements, new values have 4 elements
```

What can I do to put the ratio_rows in the index column?

Comment: Is `Ratio` a column or the index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use pd.DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_list, index=ratio_rows)
```

not sure why you want to change the index name. It is safe to keep it by default, but you can change it at any moment with:

```
df.index.name = 'Ratios'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Ratios` is the index, you can use a single call to [`pd.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html):

```
data = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_list,
                    index=pd.Index(['ROA', 'ROE', 'ROI'], name='Ratios'))
```

With your code:

```
col_list = ['A', 'B', 'C']
ratio_rows = ['ROA', 'ROE', 'ROI']

data = pd.DataFrame(columns=col_list, index=ratio_rows)
data.index.names = ['Ratios']
```

Output:

```
          A    B    C
Ratios               
ROA     NaN  NaN  NaN
ROE     NaN  NaN  NaN
ROI     NaN  NaN  NaN
```

If you want empty strings in place of `NaN`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame('', columns=col_list,
                    index=pd.Index(['ROA', 'ROE', 'ROI'], name='Ratios'))
```

Output:

```
       A B C
Ratios      
ROA         
ROE         
ROI
```